# Attach gdb to process before I know the process id

Tags: debugging, unix, gdb

I am debugging a process on a web server running Linux. The process is invoked once a request is coming from a web-page. In order to debug the process, I look at the running processes list (using `top`), I spot the relevant process (named `apache2`) by it's CPU usage (quite easy, since it is usually on top of the list), and I attach the gdb session to the process id. Of course I can call the `attach PID` command only after the process is up.

The only problem is that this process-id-spotting takes a second or two, so I cannot stop at functions which are called during the first second or two. (The whole process takes about a minute so in most cases it is not a problem).

Is there any way of doing this automatically, so I can save these couple of seconds and start the attachment earlier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach to the parent process and [catch `fork`s](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Catchpoints.html#Set-Catchpoints). Don't forget to [`set follow-fork-mode child`](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html#Forks).